# Reuseable C++11 Thread

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

I'm learning about threading support in C++. I've got a basic understanding of thread-pools and why creating and destroying threads on some systems can be expensive. As far as I'm aware C++11 doesn't have any built in support for worker/background threads. `std::thread` is only designed to perform one task which you set in the constructor; it then destroys the thread after the task is complete.

At the moment I have no use for a fully fledged thread-pool but I would like to be able to reuse a thread for different tasks after I create it. I've created a simple class that will accept any function or method wrapped in a lambda and will then execute it exactly once. The reusable thread object should not destruct until the work function is fully complete.

This is the implementation:

```
class Reusable_Thread
{
    public:
        Reusable_Thread()
            : m_thread_pause(true), m_thread_quit(false),
              m_thread(&Reusable_Thread::thread_worker, this)
        { }

        ~Reusable_Thread()
        {
            m_thread_quit = true;
            m_thread.join();
        }

        bool get_readiness() const { return m_thread_pause; }

        bool set_work(const std::function<void()>& work_func)
        {
            if (get_readiness())
            {
                m_work_func = work_func;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    private:
        std::atomic<bool> m_thread_pause;
        std::atomic<bool> m_thread_quit;
        std::thread m_thread;
        std::function<void()> m_work_func;

        void thread_worker()
        {
            while (!m_thread_quit)
            {
                if (!m_thread_pause)
                {
                    m_work_func();
                    m_thread_pause = true;
                }
            }
        }
};
```

And this is some example usage:

```
int main()
{
    Reusable_Thread thread;

    auto f1 = [&] () { /* do some work */ };
    thread.set_work(f1);

    while (thread.get_readiness() == false)
    {
        // do some other stuff
    }

    // set some new work
    auto f2 = [&] () { /* do some new work */ };
    thread.set_work(f2);

    // maybe call f1 again, depends if f2 has finished yet
    if (!thread.set_work(f1))
    {
        // thread too busy to call f1, call it on the main thread
        f1();
    }

    // thread won't destruct until work has finished
    return 0;
}
```

Are there any problems with implementing a reusable thread this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## A nice way to warm your cup of tea

> Are there any problems with implementing a reusable thread this way?

Yes. Let's have a look at a slightly different main:

```
int main()
{
    Reusable_Thread thread;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    return 0;
}
```

This should just wait for 10 seconds and then exit, right?

```bash
$ g++ reusablethread.cc -std=c++11 -pthread -o demo
$ /usr/bin/time ./demo
10.00user 0.00system 0:10.00elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3148maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+129minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Nope. It actually runs full throttle. This is due to your choice of

```
void thread_worker()
{
    while (!m_thread_quit)
    {
        if (!m_thread_pause)
        {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't the fault of `std::atomic<>`, but your design. If we don't have something to do, we shouldn't check immediately afterwards. Instead, we should wait. More on that later.

## howdoiturnthison

Your class is currently missing features to toggle `m_thread_pause`, which makes it hard to reason about other behaviour. I *guess* you're just missing `m_thread_pause = false` in `set_work`, e.g.

```
bool set_work(const std::function<void()>& work_func)
{
    if (get_readiness())
    {
        m_work_func = work_func;
        m_thread_pause = false;     // here, but wrong, see below
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, the name `get_readiness` is misleading. *What* is ready? The internal thread? Is the work slot free? `is_paused` is much better.

## Race condition `m_work_func` and `m_thread_pause`

Assume we have our `Reusable_Thread rthread` and it's currently paused. We have access on our `rthread` from two threads `A` and `B`. Both call `set_work`. What happens?

```
void foo(){ puts("foo"); }
void bar(){ puts("bar"); }

void thread_Alice(Reusable_Thread & rthread) {
   rthread.set_work(foo);
}

void thread_Bob(Reusable_Thread & rthread) {
   rthread.set_work(bar);
}

int main(){
    Reusable_Thread rthread;
    std::thread A(thread_Alice, std::ref(rthread));
    std::thread B(thread_Alice, std::ref(rthread));
    A.join();
    B.join();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    return 0;
}
```

It's certainly possible that the result is `foo`. It's also possible that the result is `bar`. But it's also possible that it's neither and your program crashes:

1. We create the `std::thread` in `rthread`, we call it `R`
2. We create the `std::thread`s `A` and `B`. Neither run yet.
3. `A` gets scheduled. It calls `set_work` and:

   - checks `m_thread_pause` (`get_readiness()`)
   - sets the worker to `foo`
   - yields due to scheduling
4. `B` gets scheduled. It calls `set_work` and

   - checks `m_thread_pause` (`get_readiness()`, still `true`)
   - yields
5. `A` gets scheduled. It resumes the execution and

   - sets `m_thread_pause` to `false`
   - `returns`

   `A`'s thread of execution has ended.
6. `R` gets scheduled. It

   - checks `m_thread_quit` (is `false`)
   - checks `m_thread_pause` (is `false` due to `A`)
   - starts reading the `std::function<>` `m_work_fun`.
   - yields while reading
7. `B` gets scheduled. It finishes its call to `set_work`:

   - sets the worker to `bar`, ***although `R` currently reads from it***
   - yields
8. `R` gets scheduled. It finishes reading `m_work_fun` and ends up with a corrupt `std::function<...>` and uses `operator()`. Your program crashes.
9. Even if your program didn't crash, after `R` sets `m_thread_pause` to `true`, `B` gets scheduled and finishes `set_work`, thus setting `m_thread_pause` to `false` and the corrupt function gets called again.

So depending on where the threads get interrupted, you end up with either:

- bar
- foo
- bar
  bar
- foo
  foo
- foo
  bar
- bar
  foo
- *crash*

So, how does one get rid of this? Usually, you would use `std::atomic::exchange` or [`std::atomic::compare_exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) on `m_thread_pause`:

```
bool set_work(const std::function<void()>& work_func)
{
    if (m_thread_pause.exchange(false)) // old value was true
    {
        m_work_func = work_func;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work either, because `R` could start using `m_work_func` before it's actually set. The underlying problem here is that `m_work_func` and `m_thread_pause` are intertwined.

## Third wheel to the rescue

We can decouple this by using a third `atomic<bool>`, that checks whether the function can be set safely:

```
bool set_work(const std::function<void()>& work_func)
{
    if (!m_function_ready && m_thread_pause.exchange(false))
    {
        m_work_func = work_func;
        m_function_ready = true;
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Remember, only one thread will see `m_thread_pause` as `true`, due to the atomic exchange, so we're save from the previous `A`/`B` race.

```
void thread_worker()
{
    while (!m_thread_quit)
    {
        if (!m_thread_pause && m_function_ready)
        {
            m_work_func();
            m_thread_pause = true;
            m_function_ready = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, both the `m_thread_pause` and `m_function_ready` are checked, and the checks make sure that our function is actually set.

The memory ordering `std::memory_order_seq_cst` could be slightly relaxed (not to be confused with `memory_order_relaxed`!), but it's not trivial to get this right.

However, remember the problem in the first section of this review? You're still using active polling. A small `sleep` can help here:

```
void thread_worker()
{
    while (!m_thread_quit)
    {
        if (!m_thread_pause && m_function_ready)
        {
            m_work_func();
            m_thread_pause = true;
            m_function_ready = false;
        } else {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        }           
    }
}
```

Note that still uses more CPU power than it has to. Which brings us to condition variables.

## Wait until notified

Condition variables provide a way to get notified instead of actively checking conditions. They have to be used with a mutex, so they have a  overhead compared to atomic operations. Still, they [have their use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16350473/1139697).

In this case, you would add a `std::mutex` and a `std::condition_variable` to your class:

```
private:
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
```

In `set_work`, you notify all thread that are currently waiting:

```
bool set_work(const std::function<void()>& work_func)
{
    if (!m_function_ready && m_thread_pause.exchange(false))
    {
        m_work_func = work_func;
        m_function_ready = true;

        m_cv.notify_all();       // <- notify all waiting threads

        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

And `worker_thread`, you wait if `m_thread_pause` is false:

```
void thread_worker()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);  // <- lock the mutex

    while (!m_thread_quit)
    {
        if (!m_thread_pause && m_function_ready)
        {
            m_work_func();
            m_thread_pause = true;
            m_function_ready = false;
        } else {
            m_cv.wait(lock);  // <- wait
        }           
    }
}
```

Note that the `std::unique_lock` is placed outside the `while` loop to keep the number of lock aquires/releases to a minimum.

However, we have to make sure that the thread wakes up when we want to stop it, so we have to change the destructor slightly:

```
    ~Reusable_Thread()
    {
        m_thread_quit = true;
        m_cv.notify_all();
        m_thread.join();
    }
```

## TL;DR

Make sure that you don't introduce race conditions and avoid `while(true){if(false){ … }}`. Use proper names for methods and check the behavior on non-trivial examples.

Comment: Howdoiturnthison made me laugh. The line is there in the original source but I accidentally removed it whilst deleting superfluous comments before posting.

Your answer is a great help, I hadn't considered running threads on threads or that the scheduler might stop an assignment halfway through (with hindsight it makes sense, its why we have atomics).

Condition variables are new to me but from what you've explained, doesn't it make `m_function_ready` redundant? It doesn't matter if `m_thread_pause` is true for a little while whilst we assign `m_work_func` because the loop is locked.

Comment: After looking at the standard it turns out it does matter because `std::condition_variable` may spuriously wake up the thread. This would leave us back in the same position as the original code where the thread may be unpaused but `m_work_func`may not be fully assigned.